# Preciso enviar uma requisição POST com 4 parâmetros (login, senha, cidade, XML) em java

Tags: java, android

Bom dia, galera preciso enviar esses quatro parâmetros para o servidor emitir uma nota, os dados da nota serão passados pelo XML, que aliás já esta todo correto, mais como eu faço essa requisição POST via java enviando estes dados?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse são os dados que tenho que enviar como mostra o manual.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo usar Apache HttpClient. 
É mais rápido e fácil de implementar.

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://www.seusite.com/");
NameValuePair[] data = {
    new NameValuePair("login", "sss"),
    new NameValuePair("senha", "aaaa")
    new NameValuePair("cidade", "xxxx")
    new NameValuePair("fi", yourFILE)
};
post.setRequestBody(data);
// Execute o método e lida com todas as respostas de erro.
...
InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
// lida com resposta.
```

Comment: Olá Luiz, assim não funcionou, essa classe NameValuePair não tem na biblioteca que baixei, e a classe BasicNameValuePair que achei não aceita File como segundo parâmetro.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de pesquisar bastante encontrei minha solução e aqui comportilho.

Path path = Paths.get("/Users/alexandre/notaEnvio.xml");

```
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(path.toFile(), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
    StringBody stringBody1 = new StringBody("15425039000128", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    StringBody stringBody2 = new StringBody("154250", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    StringBody stringBody3 = new StringBody("7513", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    // 
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    builder.addPart("login", stringBody1);
    builder.addPart("senha", stringBody2);
    builder.addPart("cidade", stringBody3);
    builder.addPart("f1", fileBody);
    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

    //
    post.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```